# Trajetória de um objeto usando canvas no javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

A dúvida é a seguinte, eu consegui desenvolver o exercício até certo ponto, após isso, como não conheço muito de javascript, caso eu mande o quadrado voltar na diagonal, o quadrado volta antes devido as coordenadas que já foram utilizadas, é meio complexo de explicar, mas está dando conflito nas coordenadas porque já foram utilizadas anteriormente no trajeto.

A questão é, como faço para o quadrado voltar na diagonal conforme a imagem demonstra? **(O quadrado parte da esquerda, fazendo o percurso)** 90% do exercício está feito, só preciso disso.

Obrigado

[image: Trajetória do quadrado azul]

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('minha-tela'); 
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//definir o ínicio do desenho
var x = 0
var y = 150;
var l = 0;
//a função gameloop é chamada aqui
requestAnimationFrame(gameloop);
function gameloop() {

  if(x<=700 && y==150)  
  x = x + 10;

  if (x>=700 && y>=0)
  y=y-10;

  if (x>=350 && y<=0) 
  x=x-10; 



  desenharQuadrado(x,y);



   //incrementar a variável x indicando o deslocamento para a direita
  //chama novamente o ciclo da animação

  requestAnimationFrame(gameloop);

}
function desenharQuadrado(pX,pY) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 400); //antes de fazer o desenho é preciso limpar o canvas
  ctx.fillStyle = '#00F';
  ctx.fillRect(pX, pY, 100, 100);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="minha-tela" width="800" height="400" style="border: #F00 solid 1px;"> </canvas>
```

---

Comment: Douglaslb, não remova informações da pergunta que façam com que ela fique meio sem sentido para quem for ler (tal como a figura que mostra qual é a trajetória desejada e parte da explicação do problema), mesmo se a pergunta já tiver sido respondida. Dessa forma, outras pessoas poderão também aprender utilizando o código tanto da pergunta quanto da resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse é o código que controla a trajetória do quadrado:

```
  if(x<=700 && y==150)  
  x = x + 10;

  if (x>=700 && y>=0)
  y=y-10;

  if (x>=350 && y<=0) 
  x=x-10;
```

Esse código está usando uma abordagem de determinar a próxima posição a partir da posição atual. Entretanto, isso não vai funcionar sem alguma mudança na abordagem porque há duas linhas que se cruzam, o que significa que haveria duas trajetórias possíveis e você não saberia qual seguir.

Mas arrumar isso é fácil. Se você guardar em uma variável qual é o segmento de reta que está sendo percorrido (1, 2, 3 ou 4), você vai poder saber facilmente a trajetória a ser seguida.

A trajetória do quarto segmento é dada ao diminuir o `x` e aumentar o `y` simultaneamente.

Ou seja, dentro da sua função `gameloop` dá para fazer algo assim:

```
  if (linha === 1) {
    x += 10;
    if (x > 700) linha = 2;
  } else if (linha === 2) {
    y -= 10;
    if (y < 0) linha = 3;
  } else if (linha === 3) {
    x -= 10;
    if (x < 350) linha = 4;
  } else if (linha == 4) {
    x -= 10;
    y += 10;
    if (x < 0) linha = 5;
  }
```

É possível escrever-se isso com um `switch` também. Mas não gosto de usar e nem de ensinar o `switch` porque ele tem uma forte tendência de ser muito mal-utilizado.

Você inicia `linha` com 1. Quando chegar em 5, ele vai parar. Eis o resultado:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('minha-tela'); 
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Início do desenho.
var x = 0
var y = 150;
var linha = 1;

requestAnimationFrame(gameloop);

function gameloop() {
  if (linha === 1) {
    x += 10;
    if (x > 700) linha = 2;
  } else if (linha === 2) {
    y -= 10;
    if (y < 0) linha = 3;
  } else if (linha === 3) {
    x -= 10;
    if (x < 350) linha = 4;
  } else if (linha == 4) {
    x -= 10;
    y += 10;
    if (x < 0) linha = 5;
  }

  desenharQuadrado(x,y);
  requestAnimationFrame(gameloop);
}

function desenharQuadrado(pX,pY) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 400); // Limpar o canvas.
  ctx.fillStyle = '#00F';
  ctx.fillRect(pX, pY, 100, 100);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="minha-tela" width="800" height="400" style="border: #F00 solid 1px;" />
```

Comment: Se desejar um novo exercício para aprofundar estudos, tente criar uma função baseada na resposta acima mas agora passe por parâmetro um array dos pontos que deseja percorrer, assim como a sua velocidade.